# Most Recent Time for different variables in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having a problem where I need to find out the most recent dates for different characters. 
For example:

```
Traveler   Date
A          11/20/2017
B          11/20/2017
A          11/28/2018
B          11/28/2018 
A          12/30/2018
```

I want the results to be like:

```
Traveler   Date
A          12/30/2018
B          11/28/2018
```

I have tried max and min, but neither of them gave me the desired answers. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: If a traveler cannot appear twice on the same date, you can simply do `df.sort_values(["Date","Traveler"],ascending=False)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert Date to Datetime with [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [DataFrame.GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and max:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df_last=df.groupby('Traveler')['Date'].max().reset_index()
print(df_last)


  Traveler       Date
0        A 2018-12-30
1        B 2018-11-28
```

Comment: This method did work, but when I tried to assign a header to the date column, it adds a new column with the new header that only shows NaT in that column.  How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you show your question and show your expected dataframe with this column aggregate?

Comment: the expected data frame is the one posted in the question where it should contain a header "Date" for the second column.

Comment: Sorry, you only need  `reset_index` to set `'Traveler'` like columns. Please tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

What I will do `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates('Traveler',keep='last')
Out[94]: 
  Traveler       Date
3        B 2018-11-28
4        A 2018-12-30
```